# Social tables authentication with code returns 'Code has expired' message

Tags: social-tables

Am request social table token endpoint from angular application with the code (authorization_code as grant type). It returns 'code has expired' exception. Can someone help me on this

Comment: Give more information of what you did, code, etc

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using an expired code.
You'll need to get a new code when the old one expires.

Have you taken a look at the tutorial?

https://developer.socialtables.com/docs/apps/tutorial.html

Comment: Yes I did.. it's what I found...very first time only I could able to get the tokens, second time I hit , it returns code expired. Then again to logout the account and login again.

Comment: Sounds like something isn't configured correctly in your code. You might try getting our example app up and running https://github.com/socialtables/example-app